# Typo3 CMS 8.7.15 // restrict search results to current language

Tags: typo3, typoscript, multilingual

I'm using the TYPO3 version TYPO3 CMS 8.7.15. with  a multilanguage setup. Everything works fine. German is the default language. The other configured languages are english, portugeese and chinese. The problem is when I try to search keywords in different languages than the current language, i get results from the other translations. I want to ask for the right settings to display only search results in the current language from the current content.

```
config {
    linkVars = L
    uniqueLinkVars = 1
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    sys_language_overlay = 1
    sys_language_uid = 0
    locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8
    htmlTag_langKey = de
    language = de
}
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 0


# SPRACHE: ENGLISCH
[globalVar = GP:L=6]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 6
        language = en
        locale_all = en_GB.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = en
    }

    pugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 6
[global]

# SPRACHE: PORTUGIESISCH
[globalVar = GP:L=7]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 7
        language = pt
        locale_all = pt_PT.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = pt
    }

    plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 7
[global]

# SPRACHE: CHINESISCH (EINFACH)
[globalVar = GP:L=8]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 8
        language = zh
        locale_all = zh_CN.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = zh
    }

    plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 8
[global]
```

The only way to configure it right is the plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang variable. But this has no effect to my search results. What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your search field into your menu for example (fluidtemplate) the `<f:form.hidden name="search[languageUid]"`is not filled. So the results shows all languages.

I helped myself by using a `lib` that gives me the current language.

#### Fluid:

```
<f:form.hidden name="search[languageUid]" value="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.language')}" />
```

#### Typoscript Setup:

```
# German language
temp.language = TEXT
temp.language.value = 0

# English language
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    temp.language.value = 1
[global]

lib.language < temp.language
```